# Objects won't cast a shadow on an other object

Tags: light, lighting, shadows

I'm making a bowl of Milk with some Cereal inside it for a scene. It just wasn't looking right and I was wondering why.

Until I noticed that there were no shadows being casted on the Milk! Neither from the bowl nor the Cereal.

[image]

I've gone through every setting I could think of that could have anything to do with shadows, but I just can't find the issue. Normals are facing the correct way. I double checked.

EDIT: Included .Blend File

EDIT2: Now actually included the .Blend File.

[image]

Comment: Hello, I don't see any link to the blend file

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to this website. I included a link now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your milk has *Subsurface Scattering*, it tends to make the shadow disappear